# Again WPA Connection problem even after changed to latest version ..please help

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wep, wpa

I am using hostapd, wireless tools with madwifi for my wireless ap in my board.
The WEP, WPA-PSK connections and communications between my board with linux and my desktop PC, Windows XP SP2 (with Olitec USB wireless) are fine.

But when I configured the WPA type, the connection seems established but shows the status *"TKIP - Key Absent"* in the security dialog box.

Anyone faced this problem?

Am attaching the conf files and the connection status.

In the AP side am complaining .

I am using the in built radius server conf with the hostapd 0.4.7

### hostapd.conf

interface=ath0

driver=madwifi

logger_syslog=0

logger_syslog_level=0

logger_stdout=0

logger_stdout_level=0

debug=0

eapol_key_index_workaround=1

dump_file=/tmp/hostapd.dump.0.0

ssid=Renjith G wpa

wpa=1

wpa_passphrase=mypassphrase

wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-EAP

wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP

wpa_group_rekey=600

## macaddr_acl=2  /* commented */

## ieee8021x=1   /* commented */

eap_authenticator=1

own_ip_addr=172.16.25.1

nas_identifier=renjithg.com

auth_server_addr=172.16.25.1

auth_server_port=1812

auth_server_shared_secret=key1

ca_cert=/flash1/ca.crt

server_cert=/flash1/server.crt

eap_user_file=/etc/hostapd.eap_user

### hostapd.eap_user

"*@renjithg.com" TLS

And the commands am using are

wlanconfig ath0 create wlandev wifi0 wlanmode ap

iwconfig ath0 essid Renjith channel 6

ifconfig ath0 192.168.25.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

hostapd -ddd /etc/hostapd.conf

Please correct if am wrong ..

Also am getting the debug messages on my AP when am connecting in my windows machine through WPA

~/wlanexe # ./hostapd -ddd /etc/hostapd.conf

Configuration file: /etc/hostapd.conf
Line 18: obsolete eap_authenticator used; this has been renamed to eap_server

madwifi_set_iface_flags: dev_up=0
Using interface ath0 with hwaddr 00:0b:6b:33:8c:30 and ssid 'Renjith G wpa'
madwifi_set_ieee8021x: enabled=1
madwifi_configure_wpa: group key cipher=1
madwifi_configure_wpa: pairwise key ciphers=0xa
madwifi_configure_wpa: key management algorithms=0x1
madwifi_configure_wpa: rsn capabilities=0x0
madwifi_configure_wpa: enable WPA= 0x1
madwifi_set_iface_flags: dev_up=1
madwifi_set_privacy: enabled=1

WPA: group state machine entering state GTK_INIT
GMK - hexdump(len=32): 9c 77 cd 38 5a 60 3b 16 8a 22 90 e8 65 b3 c2 86 40 5c be c3 dd 84 3e df 58 1d 16 61 1d 13 d1 f2
GTK - hexdump(len=32): 02 78 d7 d3 5d 15 e3 89 9c 62 a8 fe 8a 0f 40 28 ba dc cd bc 07 f4 59 88 1c 08 84 2b 49 3d e2 32
WPA: group state machine entering state SETKEYSDONE
madwifi_set_key: alg=TKIP addr=00:00:00:00:00:00 key_idx=1
Flushing old station entries
madwifi_sta_deauth: addr=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff reason_code=3
Deauthenticate all stations
l2_packet_receive - recvfrom: Network is down
Wireless event: cmd=0x8c03 len=20

New STA
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK entering state INITIALIZE
madwifi_del_key: addr=00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 key_idx=0
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK_GROUP entering state IDLE
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK entering state AUTHENTICATION
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK entering state AUTHENTICATION2

IEEE 802.1X: 4 bytes from 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09
   IEEE 802.1X: version=1 type=1 length=0
Wireless event: cmd=0x8c04 len=20
madwifi_del_key: addr=00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 key_idx=0

ioctl[unknown???]: Invalid argument

WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK entering state DISCONNECTED
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK entering state INITIALIZE
madwifi_del_key: addr=00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 key_idx=0
ioctl[unknown???]: Invalid argument
Wireless event: cmd=0x8c03 len=20
  New STA
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK entering state INITIALIZE
madwifi_del_key: addr=00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 key_idx=0
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK_GROUP entering state IDLE
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK entering state AUTHENTICATION
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK entering state AUTHENTICATION2
IEEE 802.1X: 4 bytes from 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09

IEEE 802.1X: version=1 type=1 length=0
<> Register Fail
<> Register Fail
Wireless event: cmd=0x8c04 len=20
madwifi_del_key: addr=00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 key_idx=0
ioctl[unknown???]: Invalid argument
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK entering state DISCONNECTED
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK entering state INITIALIZE
madwifi_del_key: addr=00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 key_idx=0
ioctl[unknown???]: Invalid argument
Wireless event: cmd=0x8c03 len=20

New STA
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK entering state INITIALIZE
madwifi_del_key: addr=00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 key_idx=0
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK_GROUP entering state IDLE
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK entering state AUTHENTICATION
WPA: 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 WPA_PTK entering state AUTHENTICATION2
IEEE 802.1X: 4 bytes from 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09
   IEEE 802.1X: version=1 type=1 length=0

**NOW am getting the following error message with latest tools.**
**This is the latest error messages..please refer this only..**

~/wlanexe # ./hostapd -ddd /etc/hostapd.conf

TLS: Trusted root certificate(s) loaded

madwifi_set_iface_flags: dev_up=0

madwifi_set_privacy: enabled=0

BSS count 1, BSSID mask ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff (0 bits)

Flushing old station entries

madwifi_sta_deauth: addr=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff reason_code=3

ioctl[IEEE80211_IOCTL_SETMLME]: Invalid argument

madwifi_sta_deauth: Failed to deauth STA (addr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff reason 3)

Could not connect to kernel driver.

Deauthenticate all stations

madwifi_sta_deauth: addr=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff reason_code=2

ioctl[IEEE80211_IOCTL_SETMLME]: Invalid argument

madwifi_sta_deauth: Failed to deauth STA (addr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff reason 2)

madwifi_set_privacy: enabled=0

madwifi_del_key: addr=00:00:00:00:00:00 key_idx=0

madwifi_del_key: addr=00:00:00:00:00:00 key_idx=1

madwifi_del_key: addr=00:00:00:00:00:00 key_idx=2

madwifi_del_key: addr=00:00:00:00:00:00 key_idx=3

Using interface ath0 with hwaddr 00:0b:6b:33:8c:30 and ssid 'RenjithGwpa'

SSID - hexdump_ascii(len=11):
     52 65 6e 6a 69 74 68 47 77 70 61                  RenjithGwpa

PSK (ASCII passphrase) - hexdump_ascii(len=12):
     6d 79 70 61 73 73 70 68 72 61 73 65               mypassphrase

PSK (from passphrase) - hexdump(len=32): a6 55 3e 76 94 8b d9 81 a1 22 5e 24 29 83 33 86 11 a8 7e 93 19 7c a9 ab ab cc 12 58 37 e5 35 b6
RADIUS local address: 172.16.25.1:1024

madwifi_set_ieee8021x: enabled=1

madwifi_configure_wpa: group key cipher=1

madwifi_configure_wpa: pairwise key ciphers=0xa

madwifi_configure_wpa: key management algorithms=0x1

madwifi_configure_wpa: rsn capabilities=0x0

madwifi_configure_wpa: enable WPA=0x1

WPA: group state machine entering state GTK_INIT (VLAN-ID 0)

GMK - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]

GTK - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]

WPA: group state machine entering state SETKEYSDONE (VLAN-ID 0)

madwifi_set_key: alg=TKIP addr=00:00:00:00:00:00 key_idx=1

madwifi_set_privacy: enabled=1

madwifi_set_iface_flags: dev_up=1

ath0: Setup of interface done.

l2_packet_receive - recvfrom: Network is down

Wireless event: cmd=0x8b1a len=24

Wireless event: cmd=0x8c03 len=20
  New STA

ioctl[unknown???]: Invalid argument

madwifi_process_wpa_ie: Failed to get WPA/RSN IE

Failed to get WPA/RSN information element.

Data frame from not associated STA 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09

Wireless event: cmd=0x8c04 len=20

Wireless event: cmd=0x8c03 len=20

New STA

ioctl[unknown???]: Invalid argument

madwifi_process_wpa_ie: Failed to get WPA/RSN IE

Failed to get WPA/RSN information element.

Data frame from not associated STA 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09

Data frame from not associated STA 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09

Data frame from not associated STA 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09

Wireless event: cmd=0x8c04 len=20

Wireless event: cmd=0x8c03 len=20

New STA

ioctl[unknown???]: Invalid argument

madwifi_process_wpa_ie: Failed to get WPA/RSN IE

Failed to get WPA/RSN information element.

Data frame from not associated STA 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you say WPA-PSK works fine, but WPA (as in, WPA with 802.1X authentication, a.k.a. "WPA-Enterprise") doesn't?

Which side is complaining, the AP or the STA?

You might want to look at what's going on with your 802.1X supplicant on your STA, the 802.1X  authenticator on your AP, and RADIUS server (if you're using one). Did EAP complete successfully? Did the RADIUS server send the RADIUS Access-Accept message to the Authenticator on the AP? Did the RADIUS server send the RADIUS Key message to Authenticator on the AP? Did the AP's 802.1X authenticator hand the PMK down to the code that handles the TKIP key handshake on the AP? Did the 802.1X client on the STA hand the PMK down to the code that handles the TKIP key handshake on the STA?

#### Update 4/4 based on your additional information:

This looks interesting:

```
IEEE 802.1X: 4 bytes from 00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 IEEE 802.1X: version=1 type=1 length=0 Wireless event: cmd=0x8c04 len=20 madwifi_del_key: addr=00:0a:78:a0:0b:09 key_idx=0  

ioctl[unknown???]: Invalid argument
```

I should warn you that although I'm deeply familiar with 802.11, 802.1X and WPA, I'm not an expert on the hostapd and madwifi implementations in particular. So with that said, it looks like you're using a built-in authenticator in hostapd on your AP to do EAP-TLS. It looks like the STA is sending an eapol-start, and hostapd is trying to tell the madwifi driver to delete any keys for that STA since the stay is reauthenticating. But it looks like the madwifi driver is choking on the ioctl to delete the key.

Are you sure you're running a version of madwifi that's known to work with the version of hostapd you're running?

Also, why not clear up that other warning by fixing line 18 of your hostapd.conf?

Comment: could you please give me your contact details?

Comment: Spiff , i can successfully communicate using the WEP and WPA-PSK (which ensures the version matching between hostapd and madwifi) right?

yes i changed the line 18 warning in hostapd.conf